# How do I connect to the database, shoot and email and update database simultaneously when the user clicks the submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm a business graduate and not a professional coder. Was just trying this out but was stuck at this point. I hope this won't be difficult for the professionals here at Stackoverflow. Below is the code:

PHP:

```
<?php

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripcslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

        //Define variables to set empty values

        $name = $email = $co_name = $website = $message = $query = "";
        $nameerr = $emailerr = $co_nameerr = $websiteerr = $messageerr = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameerr = "Name is required";
                } else {
                    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$name)){
                        $nameerr = "Only letters and whitespaces allowed";
                        }
                    }
                if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailerr = "Email is required";
                } else {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                        $emailerr = "Email is invalid";
                        }
                    }
                if (empty($_POST["co_name"])) {
                    $co_name = "";
                } else {
                    $co_name = test_input($_POST["co_name"]);
                    }
                if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
                    $website = "";
                } else {
                    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
                     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
                        $websiteerr = "Invalid URL";
                        }
                    }
                if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
                    $messageerr = "Message is required";
                } else {
                    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
                    }

                if (isset($name, $email, $co_name, $website, $message)){
                $query = "INSERT INTO `visitors_message` (`name`,`company_name`, `email`, `website`,`email`, `message`)
                            VALUES ('$name', '$co_name','$email', '$website'
                                        , $message)";
            }
        }


    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
        <p class="desc">
            <label>
            Name*: 
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameerr; ?></span>
            </br></br>
            <label>
            Company Name:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="co_name" id="co_name">
            </br></br>
            <label>
            Website:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="website" id="website">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteerr; ?></span>
            </br></br>
            <label>
            Email*:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailerr; ?></span>
            </br></br>
            <label>
            Message*:
            </label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="55" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $messageerr; ?></span>
            </br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The coding style is nice, by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following after the line of `$query` assignment:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else {
    // Inserting data into the database
    $mysqli->query($query);

    // Sending email:
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "My subject";
    $msg = "Thank you :)";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

And in your code, in the query string, you've forgot to place the `$message` inside the qoutition marks.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. BTW does this mean that the above code is fine? I also want to send an email simultaneously. How can I do that?

Comment: @saadi123 What do you mean by _"fine"_ ?

Comment: @saadi123 The answer is updated for the email part, take a look :)

Comment: By fine I mean that the logic is fine. Right?

Comment: @saadi123 Yes, of course. for example the now obsolete `mysql_*` is not used, It has the possible connection error check and inserts the data into the database and sends email only when the database connection is fine and of course the required variables are already set properly by _your_ code, and finally the connection is closed properly :)

Comment: Thanks buddy. let me check this out and then update the results.